# $PA^2 + PB^2 + PC^2 + PD^2 = 4\cdot R^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $AB$ and $CD$ be two chords of a circle having radius $R$, which intersect at the point $P$ in right angle.
>
> Then prove that $PA^2 + PB^2 + PC^2 + PD^2 = 4\cdot R^2$.

Please anyone help. I am stuck here.

Comment: Do you know that $PA.PB=PC.PD$ (power of point $P$ with respect to circle) (this would be true even if the chords are not orthogonal) ?

Comment: No I don't .pls prove .

Comment: Have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point)

Comment: Yes,will u pls write the complete proof?

Comment: How so you could  not progress on this problem even after the comments ? Did you try at all?

Comment: No man, I have got my answer.and I did not get jean's point.if you have very elementary proof that a 9 th grader can underatand then pls post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$PA^2+PC^2=AC^2=(2R\sin\angle PBC)^2$$
$$PB^2+PD^2=BD^2=(2R\sin\angle PCB)^2$$

where I used the law of sines in the last equality.

You can see that: $$\sin\angle PBC=\cos\angle PCB$$ because they are complementary angles.

[image]

**Alternative solution**

We can see that:

$$PA^2+PC^2+PB^2+PD^2=AC^2+BD^2$$
[image]

Now, if we consider the right triangles $\triangle ACE$ and $\triangle APC$, we get:

$$AC:d=AP:AD$$

because they are similar; where $d$ is the diameter $AE$. Hence $AC={AP\over AD}d$.

We can get an analogous relation for $BD$, considering the similar right triangles $\triangle BDF$ and $\triangle BPC$:

[image]

$$BD:d=BP:BC$$

so $BD={BP\over BC}d$.

Replacing above these relations, we get:

$$PA^2+PC^2+PB^2+PD^2=AC^2+BD^2=\left[\left({AP\over AD}\right)^2+\left({BP\over BC}\right)^2\right]d^2$$

Now we can consider the similar right triangles $\triangle APD$ and $\triangle BPC$:

${BP\over BC}={PD\over AD}$

hence: $\left[\left({AP\over AD}\right)^2+\left({BP\over BC}\right)^2\right]d^2=\left[\left({AP\over AD}\right)^2+\left({PD\over AD}\right)^2\right]d^2=d^2=4R^2$

Comment: Actually , It is the problem of a 9 th grader .So I was looking for a more elementary proof where a/sinA= b/sin B = c/sinC= 2R is not used .

Comment: If you want, I also have a more elementary solution...

Comment: Yes, I want really.

Comment: Ok then I'll edit it later :-)